# generic type from string

Tags: json, swift, generics

EDIT: (initial example was too simplified, so I rewrote the code to be more specific)

based on http://holko.pl/2016/01/05/typed-table-view-controller/

I am trying to see if it is possible to set the generic parameter of a type from a string..

Say we have this code

```
protocol Updatable
{
    associatedtype ViewModel
    func updateWith(viewModel: ViewModel)
}

class ToasterCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var toast: String?
    func updateWith(viewModel: String) {
        toast = viewModel
        //Additional config...
    }
}
extension ToasterCell: Updatable
{
    typealias ViewModel = String
}

class PriceCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var tagPrice: Float?
    func updateWith(viewModel: Float) {
        tagPrice = viewModel
        //Additional config
    }
}
extension PriceCell: Updatable
{
    typealias ViewModel = Float
}


protocol CellConfiguratorType {

    var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
    var cellClass: AnyClass { get }

    func updateCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell)
}

class MyTypeTest<Cell> where Cell: Updatable , Cell: UITableViewCell
{
    let viewModel: Cell.ViewModel
    let reuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: Cell.self)
    let cellClass: AnyClass = Cell.self
    init(viewModel: Cell.ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    func updateCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell)
    {
        if let c = cell as? Cell
        {
            c.updateWith(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}
extension MyTypeTest: CellConfiguratorType{
}

let myTT1 = MyTypeTest<PriceCell>(viewModel: 3.76)
let myTT2 = MyTypeTest<ToasterCell>(viewModel: "Carpe Diem")
let data = [myTT1, myTT2] as [CellConfiguratorType] // data for the tableView
//register Cell calss ...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellConf = data[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellConf.reuseIdentifier)
    cellConf.updateCell(cell)
    return cell
}
```

And we want to make it so that the type T is set from a string we get from a JSON response.

```
//Some JSON {"list":[{"k":"Price","v":368.0},"{"k":"ToasterCell","v":"YOLO"},"{"k":"Toaster","v":"Space"},{"k":"PriceCell","v":1999}]}
```

the JSON value does not map directly to any object/class, So I need to use that key "k" to know witch class to use.

I tried using the string from the "k" value to setup the cell configurator.

(short example)

```
//for now let skip any logic in decoding the value / viewModel.
let myTT1 = MyTypeTest<NSClassFromString(list.first.k + "Cell")>(viewModel: list.first.v as Any)
```

All I got was following errors:

- Cannot assign value of type 'T' to type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')
- Use of undeclared type 'myTypeOBJ'

Is there a way to do this via a string, or do I really need to create a huge "if-else" structure for whatever type I could get from my JSON responses?

EDIT: 
I tried to add an init to the CellConfigurator with a param of type Cell so it can infer the Type from the param it self.

```
init(viewModel: Cell.ViewModel, inferUsing: Cell){....}
```

where I could attempt to use this (but is does not work as the PATs is getting in the way)

```
func getSafeBundelName() -> String
    {
        if let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String
        {
            return namespace
        }
        return ""
    }

let cellClass = NSClassFromString("\(getSafeBundelName()).PriceCell") as? UITableViewCell.Type
let cell = cellClass?.init()
let myTT1 = MyTypeTest(viewModel: list.first.v as Any, inferUsing: cell)
```

I get the error that the Cell type can not be infered. If I try to use the cellClass in the <> 

ex: `MyTypeTest<cellType>(viewModel: 3.76)` all it gives me is that "cellClass" is not declared. Looks to me I am hitting a dead end where PATs become impossible to infer in any way that I can see. I find this limitation very very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you downcast the result from `NSClassFromString` to a type with a known initializer that you can call.  If it will always be `Toaster` or a subclass then you can do:

```
if let myTypeOBJ = NSClassFromString("Toaster") as? Toaster.Type {
    let test = myTypeTest(someOBJ: myTypeOBJ.init())
    // test.someThing will be of type Toaster
}
```

In order for `NSClassFromString` to work you will also need to specify how you want the type name to be represented in objc, otherwise there will be some other stuff prepended to the type name:

```
@objc(Toaster)
class Toaster: NSObject
```

Comment: this works if myTypeTest is not generic. and I need myTypeTest to be generic. class myTypeTest<T> where T: NSObject

Comment: It works fine for me in a playground with the generic class in your question unless you have a different definition for "works"

Comment: myTypeTest(someOBJ: myTypeOBJ.init()) is not generic

Comment: It is, the compiler is capable of inferring the generic type by looking at the type of the object you pass in to the initializer

Comment: You need to understand the difference between what happens at compile-time and what happens at runtime.  Generics need to be able to infer their types at compile-time and `NSClassFromString` returns a class at runtime.  You need something that maps possible values in your json to types at compile-time (such as the if-else structure that you want to avoid).

Comment: .. Swift does make me miss OBJC's runtime. I just keep hitting brick walls in swift. :( got to get used to it.